# Can't make PyQt5 Gui work, python3

Tags: python-3.4, pyqt5

i've made several guis with Qt Designer and then with PyQt5 i converted the .ui to .py, however, whenever i run this code on python3 nothing happens, no gui, no errors, nothing, i'm quite new to python and i have no idea why this is happening.

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.4.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(629, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButton_15)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tableView, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_11 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_11.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_11")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_11)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.tableView_2 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_2)
        self.tableView_2.setObjectName("tableView_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tableView_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_13 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_13.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_13")
        self.pushButton_19 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_19.setObjectName("pushButton_19")
        self.horizontalLayout_13.addWidget(self.pushButton_19)
        self.pushButton_18 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_18.setObjectName("pushButton_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_13.addWidget(self.pushButton_18)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_13.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_13)
        self.horizontalLayout_12 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_12.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_12")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_12)
        self.tableView_3 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_3)
        self.tableView_3.setObjectName("tableView_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.tableView_3)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_17 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_17.setObjectName("pushButton_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_17)
        self.pushButton_16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_16.setObjectName("pushButton_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_16)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 629, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu_File = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_File.setObjectName("menu_File")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuVer = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuVer.setObjectName("menuVer")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_File.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuVer.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Agregar profesor"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Borrar profesor"))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar profesor"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Profesores"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Agregar seccion"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar seccion"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Borrar seccion"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Secciones"))
        self.pushButton_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Agregar clase"))
        self.pushButton_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar clase"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Borrar clase"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Horarios"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextGoesHere"))
        self.pushButton_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Aceptar"))
        self.pushButton_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancelar"))
        self.menu_File.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "&File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuVer.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ver"))
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) on using .py files created from .ui files? The .py file is not supposed to be directly run. You have to write some code to use your generated UI.

Comment: I see, i hadn't read that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is becuase you have ran something along the lines of:

```
pyuic5 view.ui -o view.py
```

Where view.ui is your Qt Designer file and view.py is your output file. The output file view.py isn't executable. If you look at the documentation, you will see that you can use another flag (-x) for executable.

So you can run:

```
pyuic5 view.ui -xo view.py
```

This will create the following file:

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.4.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(629, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.pushButton_15)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tableView, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_11 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_11.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_11")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_11)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.tableView_2 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_2)
        self.tableView_2.setObjectName("tableView_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.tableView_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_13 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_13.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_13")
        self.pushButton_19 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_19.setObjectName("pushButton_19")
        self.horizontalLayout_13.addWidget(self.pushButton_19)
        self.pushButton_18 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_18.setObjectName("pushButton_18")
        self.horizontalLayout_13.addWidget(self.pushButton_18)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_13.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_13)
        self.horizontalLayout_12 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_12.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_12")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_12)
        self.tableView_3 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_3)
        self.tableView_3.setObjectName("tableView_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.tableView_3)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_17 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_17.setObjectName("pushButton_17")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_17)
        self.pushButton_16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_16.setObjectName("pushButton_16")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_16)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 629, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu_File = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_File.setObjectName("menu_File")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuVer = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuVer.setObjectName("menuVer")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_File.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuVer.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Agregar profesor"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Borrar profesor"))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar profesor"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Profesores"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Agregar seccion"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar seccion"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Borrar seccion"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Secciones"))
        self.pushButton_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Agregar clase"))
        self.pushButton_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar clase"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Borrar clase"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Horarios"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextGoesHere"))
        self.pushButton_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Aceptar"))
        self.pushButton_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancelar"))
        self.menu_File.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "&File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuVer.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ver"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, you would want to keep your logic separate from the presentation. That is why once you have created the .py file using the pyuic5 command line tool you would create a separate file called app.py say:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication)

from view import Ui_MainWindow

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("app name")
    QCoreApplication.setApplicationVersion("app version")
    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("Your name")
    QCoreApplication.setOrganizationDomain("Your URL")

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Main()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```